# Get whole duration of folders and subfolders with sound files

Tags: ffmpeg

I am looking for a ffmpeg that allows me to get the whole duration of my music files. LEt's say that all are in mp3 format. I found online the following piece of code:

```
ffmpeg -i * 2>&1 | grep Duration
```

Now, how could I make it for subfolders included in the current folder?

ANSWER:

```
afinfo **/*.mp3 | awk '/estimated duration/ { print $3 }' | paste -sd+ - | bc | awk '{printf("%d:%02d:%02d:%02d\n",($1/60/60/24),($1/60/60%24),($1/60%60),($1%60))}'
```

Comment: Are you on Linux or windows?

Answer (score 3):

If you have ffmpeg installed you probly have ffprobe too.

```
man ffprobe
```

for example, to ouput **only** the duration in format seconds you can do

```
ffprobe -hide_banner -v error -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -show_entries stream=duration sound.mp3
```

If you want duration for each file you need to recurse.

```
find . -type f -name "*.mp3" -print0 | parallel -0 'echo "{} : `ffprobe -hide_banner -v error -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -show_entries stream=duration {}`"'
```

ffprobe takes some time so we parallelized

You might want to sum durations to get a whole directories hierarchy duration:

```
find . -type f -name "*.mp3" -print0 | parallel -0 ffprobe -hide_banner -v error -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -show_entries stream=duration | paste - -sd+ - | bc
```

Comment: Thanks, I just found one better way. Updated question. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Clever `paste` use! I also edited to simplify (a lot) and use this good idea! You should edit for code formating.